# Is there a way to avoid automatically adding extra space when typing two consecutive spaces in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I found that when I use a proportional font and type two consecutive spaces between words in a MS Word document, MS Word automatically increases the amount of horizontal space so that it looks far more than 2 spaces. Is this the problem of the font itself, or is there any setting in MS Word to disable this feature? I am using MS Word 2010. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Justification

Part of what you're seeing is the actual width of the space characters you enter, and part is the justification process Word uses, especially if you select full justification (flush left and right).  With full justification, Word fills in most the the extra space it needs between words.

You may be able to solve the problem by switching to left-justified.  That should pretty much stick to the spacing you enter, but will produce a "ragged" right text margin.  If you require full justification, experiment with the space characters you use.

#### Space Characters

There are actually lots of different standard-sized spaces.

[image: space characters]
*<sub>Credit: http://desktoppub.about.com/od/typespacing/a/Typesetting-Space-Characters.htm</sub>*

I don't have ready access to Word at the moment, so I can't test specific characters and combinations.  But, for example, hard spaces (non-breaking spaces) may work.  They prevent adjacent words at the end of a line from being split between lines, but they might also be treated as "fixed" spaces that Word doesn't adjust for justification.  A hard space can be entered directly using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Word may also treat spaces of different widths differently when it allocates extra spacing for justification, so you could try doubling a narrower space character.  The most commonly used of the other space characters can be inserted as a symbol:

- Select the `Insert` tab of the ribbon menu.
- On the right side, in the `Symbols` group, click `Symbol` and then `More Symbols`. The Symbol dialog box will be displayed.
- Click the `Special Characters` tab.

[image: special characters]

- Select the desired space character.
- Click the `Insert` button.

*<sub>Source: http://wordribbon.tips.net/T013071_Inserting_a_Non-Breaking_Space.html</sub>*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's useful because the symbol window is what I want to find, and it turns out there are so many types of spaces. But I can safely eliminate the possibility of justification as I already use left-aligned. I also thought the increase in space was due to auto-correct, but after checking (by pressing AutoCorrect button in the Symbols window) it is not the case. So my remedy is to (1) add a shortcut key to the En Space, (2) create a En Space, (3) Copy it, and (4) replace all "  " (double spaces) with the En Space by pasting.

Comment: The en space is half the width of an em space.  I forget whether the "standard" space is an en or em.  If it's an em, you could just replace all double-spaces with single spaces (same as "em em" to "en en", although a tiny gap may be added between characters, including spaces, so "en en" might be a hair larger than a single em).  If you need more than a single space, replace "em em" with "em en" or "em 1/4-em".